# Как грамотно распределить код PHP и поправить файл с CSS-стилями?

Tags: php, css, ide

Подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь средства разработки, в которых можно было бы быстро и грамотно выделить код, к примеру PHP?

К примеру, есть код в "быдло"виде:

```
function DateForm($date) {
global $weekday,$months,$offset,$dformat,$tformat;
$date = $date+30*24*60*60;
list($wday,$mday,$month,$year,$hour,$minutes,$hour12,$ampm) = explode("( )",date("w j n Y H i h A",$date));
if ($tformat == "AMPM") {
$newtime = " $hour12:$minutes $ampm";
} else {
$newtime = " $hour:$minutes";
}
if ($dformat == "USx") {
$newdate = " $month-$mday-$year";
} elseif ($dformat == "US") {
$month -= 1;
$newdate = "$weekday[$wday], $months[$month] $mday, $year";
} elseif ($dformat == "Euro") {
$month -= 1;
$newdate = "$weekday[$wday], $mday. $months[$month] $year";
} else {
$newdate = "$mday.$month.$year";
}
return $date;
return ($newdate=$newdate.$newtime);
}
```

В какой программе можно выделить его красиво с учетом вложенностей и привести его к такому виду с отступпами:

```
  function DateForm($date) {

  global $weekday,$months,$offset,$dformat,$tformat;

  $date = $date+30*24*60*60;

  list($wday,$mday,$month,$year,$hour,$minutes,$hour12,$ampm) = explode("( )",date("w j n Y H i h A",$date));

  if ($tformat == "AMPM") {
      $newtime = " $hour12:$minutes $ampm";
  } else {
      $newtime = " $hour:$minutes";
  }

  if ($dformat == "USx") {
      $newdate = " $month-$mday-$year";
  } elseif ($dformat == "US") {
      $month -= 1;
      $newdate = "$weekday[$wday], $months[$month] $mday, $year";
  } elseif ($dformat == "Euro") {
      $month -= 1;
      $newdate = "$weekday[$wday], $mday. $months[$month] $year";
  } else {
      $newdate = "$mday.$month.$year";
  }

  return $date;
  return ($newdate=$newdate.$newtime);

}
```

Сейчас я работаю в PHP Expert Editor.

Также, хотелось бы узнать, как можно поправить файл css-стилей... привести его к виду с отступами.

Comment: Приучивать себя нужно изначально содержать код в порядке! И чисто на заметку, чтобы не е*ться с `if|elseif|else` в бесконечных количествах, существует конструкция `switch/case`

Comment: Я стараюсь, но ведь я могу и неправильно что-то сделать, а потом запутаться, а такой фактор, как ограниченное время, не дает расслабляться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) комбинацией клавиш Ctrl+Alt+L. Можно форматировать как выделенный фрагмент кода, весь файл или все файлы в директории.

[image: reformat code]

Так же есть куча настроек того, **как**  форматировать код. Вы сами можете задавать стиль, если например в компании используется определенное форматирование, достаточно настроить форматирование на одной машине, экспортировать настройки в виде xml файла и импортировать на остальные машины, тем самым у всех будет единый формат кода.

PhpStrom умеет форматировать не только PHP:

1. Желтый - поддерживаемые языки
2. Зеленый - опции
3. Красный - как будет выглядеть код после форматирования

[image]

Comment: Здорово, спасибо!